# Apache2 is not installing in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2

```
root@Jatin-PC:/home/jatin# sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.18-2ubuntu3) but 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@Jatin-PC:/home/jatin#
```

Comment: try `sudo apt purge apache2` and then try to install it again with apt install?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: I reinstalled ubuntu. :p

Comment: Yeah, probably the best solution